# Create multiple lists from a string

Tags: r, list, mapply

I would like to create multiple lists from string. For example, when handling some data and charts I like to keep my workflow tidy and store objects within lists:

```
# For data
lstDta <- list()
# For charts
lstChrts <- list()
```

Creating more lists in the same manner looks boring and repetitive, which is not pleasant for the eye.

## Problem

Ideally I would like to create the lists using a string with names:

```
mapply(assign, c("lstDta", "lstChrts"),
       rep(as.list(1),3), pos = 1)
```

Understandably, the code below returns error:

```
    > mapply(assign, c("lstDta", "lstChrts"),
+        rep(as.list(NULL),2), pos = 1)
Error in mapply(assign, c("lstDta", "lstChrts"), rep(as.list(NULL), 2),  : 
  zero-length inputs cannot be mixed with those of non-zero length
```

It would be possible to make it run, like that:

```
mapply(assign, c("lstDta", "lstChrts"),
       rep(as.list(1),2), pos = 1)
```

but the created object is `numeric`. What I would like to achieve boils down to: *take this character vector and create an empty list for each value.*

Comment: @nrussell works like a charm

Comment: FYI, assignment chains, so if you are just trying to be concise (as opposed to dynamic) `L1=L2=L3=list()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
sapply(c("lstDta", "lstChrts"), function(n) {
    assign(n, list(), envir = .GlobalEnv)
})

ls.str()
#lstChrts :  list()
#lstDta :  list()
```